# How to attach multiple data to a jquery object using .data() in a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two plugins

```
$.fn.expect = function (expectation) {  
    return this.each(function () {  
        $(this).data('expectation', expectation);  
});  
}  
$.fn.isExpected = function () {  
    return $(this).data('expectation').call(this);  
}
```

The first is supposed to attach a series of conditions 
Example: $input == 2, $input.ToUpperCase() == $input, ($input / 2) == 1)

The second allows me to call the data attached to the first plugin and evaluate the conditionals whenever needed.

The problem is that my code in its current state only allows me to attach a single expectation per jquery object
Example:

```
$(input1).expect("$(this).val() == 2");
$(input1).expect("$(this).val() == 4");
$(input1).val(2);
$(input1).isExpected(); //this returns false as it now expects 4
```

Also, I need to be able to attach conditions at different points in the code, so that rules out writing something like

```
$(input1).expect("$(this).val() == 2 || $(this).val() == 4");
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: You are setting the data property 'expectation' each time.  That is a single property.  Every call is going to overlay it with the new value given.  Also as a side note, you do not need the `each()` in your first method.  `data()` will do an implicit each over the elements as part of the jQuery logic.

Comment: Thanks, I could try something like checking if expectation is set and then in a loop create a new 'expectation + "index"' if yes. Then I'll have to update isExpected to take a parameter equal to the index of expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store an array, an object or whatever you want in the object data storage. So you could initialize an array, store it in the data storage, and then in the next call, just push the desired values to the data storage (or better, push multiple values at once):

```
$.fn.expect = function (expectation) {

    // get all the arguments as an array
    var expectations = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);

    // for each matched element
    return this.each(function () {

        // gets the current expectations or set an empty array for the expectations
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('expectations') || [];

        // add all the passed expectations to the expectations array
        data = data.concat(expectations);

        // save the expectations 
        $this.data('expectations', data);

    });

};

$.fn.isExpected = function () {

    // reference to the current object
    var self = this;

    // use Array.prototype.every to test every expectation
    return $(this).data('expectations').every(function(expected) {

        // Apply the eval in a specific context using an intermediate function
        return (function() { return eval(expected); }).apply(self);

    });
}
```

Then you could ads one or several expectations at once:

```
$(input1).expect("$(this).val() == 2", "$(this).val() == 4");
```

Check my working example:

```js
$.fn.expect = function (expectation) {

    // get all the arguments as an array
    var expectations = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);

    // for each matched element
    return this.each(function () {

        // gets the current expectations or set an empty array for the expectations
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('expectations') || [];

        // add all the passed expectations to the expectations array
        data = data.concat(expectations);

        // save the expectations 
        $this.data('expectations', data);

    });

};

$.fn.isExpected = function () {

    // reference to the current object
    var self = this;

    // use Array.prototype.every to test every expectation
    return $(this).data('expectations').every(function(expected) {
    
        // Apply the eval in a specific context using an intermediate function
        return (function() { return eval(expected); }).apply(self);
        
    });
    
}

// Sets the input
var input = $('#test');

// Add the expectations to the field, multiple at once, or multiple or single at different instances
input.expect("$(this).val() > 0", "$(this).val() > 10");
input.expect("$(this).val() == 15");

// Text button
$('#button').click(function() {
  console.log(input.isExpected());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Test it!">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does help thanks, I'll have to test it to see if I can apply expectations twice to the same object using two different statements as opposed to adding two with one statement as you show here

Comment: @AndyStrackbein yes you can add single or multiple expectations at once or in multiple instances. I created with that purpose. Let me know if it helped or if we can improve it in some way.

Comment: @AndyStrackbein modified the snippet to add multiple expectations at different instances, multiple and single. :-)

Comment: Perfect thanks, I had previously used a while true loop and did something like if($(this).data('expectation' + index) != undefined) then bind the data with that appended index on the data name. Yours is easier to read, I'll check the performance differences too

Comment: @AndyStrackbein great, let me know if you need any further assistance with the code snippet.